# Nusphere PhpEd Debugger (With CodeIgniter ) Issues

Tags: debugging, phped

I am using Nusphere PHPED for my CodeIgniter Project. I am trying to use the debugger, it first gave me problems and I had to alter php.ini to get it to start the debug session. Now, I start the debugger from index.php, and it looks like it starts, but every time I do something (like clicking an anchor or something), it takes me back to index.php and has to start initializing everything again before it jumps to the specific task. In the log it says that the session ended and it "failed to navigate to URL localhost/project/profile" (where project is my project and profile is the controller i am targeting with the anchor)

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

you can use external browsers like IE, FF or Chrome with installed DBG debugger toolbars. One for IE is shipped and installed with PhpED and bars for FF and Chrome are avilable for free on their forum. Using debugger toolbar you can trigger debugger from the right place.